# Do I need to trim this hole bigger? I'm not sure if the glass tile could expand towards the faucet valve

Tags: tile, faucet, hole, glass

On my final stages of bathroom remodel. I have just enough room to install the sleeve over the valve stem faucet. I am concerned if the glass tile expands/contracts it will be too tight and crack the glass tile.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Glass tiles have very low to none thermal expansion

Comment: if the tile expands or contracts, then it will fall off the wall

Answer (score 3):

The glass tile should not expand or contract. The concern I have it that if you have to remove or replace the stem, it doesn't look like there's enough room to get an adjustable wrench or socket in there without possibly hitting, and cracking the glass tile.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The area where you would place a wrench is outside the opening.

Comment: @SteveB  How about getting adjustable pliers on the base so you don't torque the pipes when removing the stem.?  I can't tell from the picture.

Comment: For sure no room for that. I do have clamps holding the plumbing connections in the wall next to where stem screws into.

Comment: @SteveB Those clamps are further down away from the T connection, so the T will be used to transfer the forces to the clamps. The point of putting pliers in the base is so that you don't torque the T connection. It won't fail right away but it's not a great situation. If the stem ever gets seized up to the base, the plumber might have to smash the wall up to fix it. If he puts a wrench up to the stem and force it without a plier in the base, he knows he's going to rip stuff up behind the wall.

Comment: It would likely be me doing any maintenance. I don't want to risk cracking that glass tile by enlarging hole to fit plyers. Done deal!. It took me like 5 tiles to get holes drilled without them cracking. Could always come from other side of wall if I had to.